# Pushing object literals into an array (repeating itself..)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't think this is really an angular question, although I stumbled upon the problem while working with an angular ng-repeat directive.

I'm trying to store javascript object literals into an array using push so I can iterate through that in ng-repeat.

For example:

```
$scope.items = [];

var item = {
   name: "bob"
};

$scope.items.push(item);
item.name = "mary";
$scope.items.push(item);
```

At this point, the $scope.items[] is holding 2 instances of the name Mary, instead of having both Bob and Mary. This is counter-intuitive as I thought push was supposed to just append the next item to the end of the array.

My real code (summarized) goes something like the below:

```
$scope.items = [];

var item = {
   name: "";
};

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   // I dynamically set the item.name to some value using retrieved values from server
   item.name = someValueFromServer;

   $scope.items.push(item);
}
```

So, again, at the end of the for-loop, instead of having 10 different names, I have the SAME 10 names of the LAST one that was retrieved.

I couldn't quite figure out how to solve this, and wasn't able to find anything online either. I'm fairly new to this so it might've been I was searching for the wrong thing.

Any help would be awesome. Thanks so much!

Comment: Objects are references; you're pushing the same object.

Comment: How do I push a new reference?

Comment: $scope.items.push(angular.copy(item)) will deep copy the object, rather than the reference to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said, you are pushing an object reference into scope.items, and then changing the object. Causing all of its references to be updated.

Here are some alternatives:

```
var scope = {};
scope.items = [];
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

//Passing an anonymous object
for( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
    scope.items.push({name: arr[i]}); 
}

console.log(scope.items); ////[ { name: 1 }, { name: 2 }, { name: 3 }, { name: 4 }, { name: 5 } ]

function Item(value){
    this.value = value;
}

//Or with a defined object
scope.items2 = [];

for(var i =0, len =arr.length; i < len; i++){
    scope.items2.push(new Item(arr[i]));
}

console.log(scope.items2); //[ { value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }, { value: 4 }, { value: 5 } ]

//Or to declare item inside of the for loop, so that it is reinitialized each time
scope.items3 = [];

for(var i =0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++){
    var item = { name: 'somevalue ' + i };
    scope.items3.push(item);
}

console.log(scope.items3); /*[ { name: 'somevalue 0' },
                             { name: 'somevalue 1' },
                             { name: 'somevalue 2' },
                             { name: 'somevalue 3' },
                             { name: 'somevalue 4' } ]*/
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overwritten the same object every time.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var item = {
       name: someValueFromServer;
    };
    $scope.items.push(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm away from the computer at the moment but ill check this as soon as I get the chance. Makes sense though, thank you sir! :)